# Server returns 500 for request to http://localhost:3000/__nuxt_vite_node__/manifest failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:3000 ()

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

Created empty project of nuxt 3.0.0-rc13 using `pnpm dlx nuxi init nuxt-app`, dependencies installed using `pnpm install --shamefully-hoist`.

Deployment server started using `pnpm dev` but requests end with 500. Error says `request to http://localhost:3000/__nuxt_vite_node__/manifest failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 127.0.0.1:3000 ()`.

According to [documentation](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/commands/dev/#nuxi-dev) there is need to set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in the environment if machine is using a self-signed certificate in development.

How do I verify such a thing?
Could that be the solution to the error above?

Comment: So, just to be sure. What are you trying to achieve here? Get some HTTPS or a custom config of some sort? Or have a simple working basic project? For the first one, your [mentioned solution](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/7477#discussioncomment-3638501) is indeed the way to go. As for the second one, it works perfectly on my side. Be sure that you're using the LTS of Node (or at least v16) + your PNPM is up to date. Maybe try it with yarn or give a try to `npx nuxi init nuxt-app`. On my side, I don't have such errors (MacOS 12.6). Should work totally fine on Linux too btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP fixed the issue by upgrading from Node `v16.18.0` to `v18.12.1`.

Mainly using the current LTS: https://nodejs.org/en/ (as the docs recommend)

Answer (score 0):

Update of Node.js from 16.18.0 to 18.12.1 fixed the issue.